# Full house vs Full house

Tags: rules

If two players got a Full House...

First Player = 999AA

Second Player = TTT99

Which one of them wins?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXYXoxKLvvE 
Watch this hand for a real-world example ;-)

Comment: Tens full beats nines full: the triplet counts first.

Answer (score 8):

Each full house is first ranked by the rank of its triplet, and then by the rank of its pair. So TTT99 is ranked higher than 999AA.

Comment: and the reason for this of course is that three of a kind is ranked higher than a pair, i.e. it's harder to get the three of a kind in the full house than it is to get the pair.

Answer (score 0):

The Three-of-Kind part of your Fullhouse is higher ranked than the Pairs so following the rules of poker 10 10 10 9 9 is the winning hand

Comment: This is just a repeat of a prior answer